While loop wont end and always starts back at the top
For some reason my while loop will not break
I tried modifying the loop by using numbers to control the loop and more but it won’t work here is my current code:
escape = False #Initialize escape variable

while not escape:
    try:
        num1 = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
        oppChoice = input("Enter operation (+, -, *, /): ")
        num2 = float(input("Enter the second number: "))

        #Call the operations method with the numbers entered
        calc_instance.operations(num1, num2)

        #Using an if-elif statement to guide the print statements
        if oppChoice == "+":
            print(f"Result (Addition): {calc_instance.add}")
        elif oppChoice == "-":
            print(f"Result (Subtraction): {calc_instance.subtract}")
        elif oppChoice == "*":
            print(f"Result (Multiplication): {calc_instance.multiply}")
        elif oppChoice == "/":
            print(f"Result (Division): {calc_instance.divide}")
        else:
            print("Invalid operation choice. Please enter +, -, *, or /.")

        #Asking if the user wants to continue calculating
        end_program = input("Are you done calculating? (y/n)").lower()
        if end_program in ("y", "yes"):
            escape = True  #Set escape to True to break the loop
        elif end_program not in ("n", "no"):
            print("Please enter yes or no.")

    except ValueError:  #Handle invalid input
        print("Invalid input. Please enter valid numeric values.")


This loop exits as expected when I run it and enter "y".  Please show us the actual results from this code when you run it.

@JohnGordon how is that? calc_instance is not defined. The OP should provide a [example].

@ChukwujiobiCanon True.  But the reported behavior is that the loop doesn't break, not that there is a NameError.  So I assumed that wasn't the problem.

There is no harm in breaking out of it after setting escape to true?
Simply type break under escape = True section

There may be a problem with your calculation functions. I tested this code and it works fine. When I tested your code without the functions I was able to break out of the loop.

This is logically the same as the original code, therefore the problem must be elsewhere.  This doesn't address the true cause of the issue.

I overlooked testing, my bad

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

your loop breaks well if the user enters either "y" or "yes". It starts looping when the user enters an invalid input other than the stated value.
For example the the print statement, "Please enter yes or no." keeps looping without actually asking users for an additional user input.
Here is the modified code to break the loop. Hope it helps.
    else:
        print("Invalid operation choice. Please enter +, -, *, or /.")

    #Asking if the user wants to continue calculating
    while True:
        end_program = input("Are you done calculating? (y/n)").lower()
        if end_program in ("y", "yes"):
            escape = True #Set escape to True to break the primary loop
            break; # break from the inner loop
        elif end_program in ("n", "no"):
            break; # break from the inner loop but continue running the primary loop
        else :
            print("Please enter yes or no.")

except ValueError:  #Handle invalid input
    print("Invalid input. Please enter valid numeric values.")

